# Undefined Index in an Event+Contribution Registration Webform

Tags: civicontribute, webform-civicrm, contributions

Running Civi 4.7.27 / Drupal 7.59 + Webform Integration

I have Webforms to register Parent + Children and pay for an Event (the webforms are a bit complex, with lots of custom fields, but they used to work correctly).

Now, when I open the Webform second page (Contribution Page), I get the following message :

*Notice : Undefined index: fee_amount in wf_crm_webform_postprocess->validateParticipants() (line 410 in /home/bapaparoisse/www/www/sites/all/modules/webform_civicrm/includes/wf_crm_webform_postprocess.inc).*

However, everything seems to work correctly : the payment can be performed.
Other such but simpler Webforms seem to work wiyhout this Notice.

I don't know when this began, since those events are passed now. I just know that I made some Extensions cleaning recently.

I will be glad if someone can bring me some light about this (where does it come from ?)

Answer (score 1):

Given that is 'only' a Notice have you considered turning Notices off in the Drupal settings since it is normal practice to not display these on a production environment.

Comment: Thank you Pete, but it is also a way for me to detect errors in my configuration. BTW, is this message the sign of a configuration default ?

Comment: I wouldn't know without one of our developers looking in to it. sorry can't help more.